# C program circular array rotation terminated due to timeout

Tags: c, arrays

So i´m trying to solve a hackerrank problem (C language) where you perform k array[n] rotations, and at the end, ask for a m and print array[m].
My program is probably correct (it runs perfectly for most of tests, but some of them terminate due to timeout) , but inefficient, don´t know how to improve it.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(){
    int n; 
    int k; 
    int q; 
    scanf("%d %d %d",&n,&k,&q);
    int *a = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    int *b = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    for(int a_i = 0; a_i < n; a_i++){
       scanf("%d",&a[a_i]);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++){
        b[0] = a[n-1];
        for(int a_i = 1; a_i < n; a_i++){
        b[a_i] = a[a_i-1];
        }
        for(int a_i = 0; a_i < n; a_i++) a[a_i] = b[a_i];
    }
    for(int a0 = 0; a0 < q; a0++){
    int m; 
    scanf("%d",&m);
    printf("%d\n", b[m]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "probably correct"? Does it run and give the correct answer?

Comment: Yes ! for most of tests it gives the correct aswer, but some of them terminate due to timeout

Comment: If your code works and you want suggestions on improvements then probably [codereview.se] is a better place for this.

Comment: Oh, ok, thanks (new here).

Answer (score 1):

This looks more like an algorithms question. From what I gather, your program:

1. reads an array of size *n*;
2. rotates the array *k* positions to the right;
3. prints *q* positions from the resulting array.

The complexity is *O(kn + q)* because each of the *k* rotations is done in linear time.

You can do step 2 with just one rotation. Copy the last *k* elements from *a* to the beginning of *b* and the first *n-k* elements from *a* to the end of *b*. This decreases the complexity to *O(n + q)*.

You can further optimize the program by skipping step 2 altogether. When looking up position *m* in step 3, just look at *a*[*k - m*] (and wrap around if *k* < *m*). This decreases the complexity to *O(q)*.